# calling a function object to load your js

Tags: javascript

```
 function FriendlyChat() {
    // statements
 }

 FriendlyChat.protoype.somemethod = function() {
   // statements
 };
 FriendlyChat.protoype.somemethod2 = function() {
   //statements
 };

 window.onload = function() {
   window.friendlyChat = new FriendlyChat();
 };
```

So i noticed the above structure for js while working on a google codelab.
And I have two ques.

1. in normal objects you have to call the function i.e Object.somemethod()
   How does this structure call the methods assigned to it.
   From my limited understanding, Firendlychat.protoype.the method treats the
   function as an object and the methods are passed to the new object created on 
   window.onload.Via 
   inheritance, The object created i.e friendlychat has all these methods.
   Yet none of the methods are called in any way. How does this work?
2. Is there any advantage to structuring your code in this way other than 
   readability

Note :
Main function

```
 function FriendlyChat() {
   this.checkSetup();

   // Shortcuts to DOM Elements.
   this.messageList = document.getElementById('messages');
    this.messageForm = document.getElementById('message-form');


  // Saves message on form submit.
  this.messageForm.addEventListener('submit', this.saveMessage.bind(this));
  this.signOutButton.addEventListener('click', this.signOut.bind(this));
  this.signInButton.addEventListener('click', this.signIn.bind(this));

// Toggle for the button.
  var buttonTogglingHandler = this.toggleButton.bind(this);
  this.messageInput.addEventListener('keyup', buttonTogglingHandler);
  this.messageInput.addEventListener('change', buttonTogglingHandler);

  // Events for image upload.
  this.submitImageButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   this.mediaCapture.click();
 }.bind(this));
  this.mediaCapture.addEventListener('change', 
 this.saveImageMessage.bind(this));

   this.initFirebase();
 }
//the methods are setup here
// Sets up shortcuts to Firebase features and initiate firebase auth.
FriendlyChat.prototype.initFirebase = function() {
     this.auth = firebase.auth();
     this.database = firebase.database();
     this.storage = firebase.storage();
     // Initiates Firebase auth and listen to auth state changes.
     this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(this.onAuthStateChanged.bind(this));
    };


// Saves a new message on the Firebase DB.
FriendlyChat.prototype.saveMessage = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();


   }
};


FriendlyChat.prototype.setImageUrl = function(imageUri, imgElement) {
 imgElement.src = imageUri;
};

 // Saves a new message containing an image URI in Firebase.
// This first saves the image in Firebase storage.
FriendlyChat.prototype.saveImageMessage = function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var file = event.target.files[0];

   // Clear the selection in the file picker input.
   this.imageForm.reset();

    // Check if the file is an image.
  if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
      var data = {
       message: 'You can only share images',
        timeout: 2000
      };
        this.signInSnackbar.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(data);
       return;
   }
      // Check if the user is signed-in
     if (this.checkSignedInWithMessage()) {

    // TODO(DEVELOPER): Upload image to Firebase storage and add message.

   }
 };

// Signs-in Friendly Chat.
FriendlyChat.prototype.signIn = function() {
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  this.auth.signInWithRedirect(provider);
};

  // Signs-out of Friendly Chat.
 FriendlyChat.prototype.signOut = function() {
 this.auth.signOut();
};
```

Comment: Are you shure the `prototype` declarations are *inside* of the `constructor` ?

Comment: Ah i apologize they are outside.

Comment: And there are still a few syntax errors...

Comment: Umm. I am quite new to this approach plz propose an answer with the corrected syntax

Comment: And answers to the 2 ques above would be appreciated

Comment: I am assuming that it shows sth on the screen and when you click on it it does something? Or what do you mean by `Yet none of the methods are called in any way. How does this work?`

Comment: I have posted the full code @JonasW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the advantages I've seen when using prototype inheritance was that you can control all instances of an object. For ex:

```
 function FriendlyChat() {
   this.chatIsActive = true; 
 }

 FriendlyChat.prototype.deactivateChat = function(...rooms) {
   for (chatRoom of rooms) {
     chatRoom.chatIsActive = false;
   }
 }; 
var chat1 = new FriendlyChat();
var chat2 = new FriendlyChat();
var chatController = new FriendlyChat();

chatController.deactivateChat(chat1, chat2)
console.log(chat1.chatIsActive)
```

In ES6, however, you can do it:

```
 class FriendlyChat {
   constructor() {
     this.chatIsActive = true;
   }
   static deactivateChat(...rooms) {
     for (let chatRoom of rooms) {
       chatRoom.chatIsActive = false;
     }
   }
 }

var chat1 = new FriendlyChat();
var chat2 = new FriendlyChat();

FriendlyChat.deactivateChat(chat1, chat2)
console.log(chat1.chatIsActive)
```

And the another advantage of using prototype is that you can save memory spaces when you make an object from *new* keyword. For instance, the code in ES5 above, you can see chat1 and chat2 I've made by using *new*. Then chat1 and chat2 will be able to access deactivateChat() method which is in a sharing-space. It's because of the concept, called prototype-chaining.

And the next ES6 version is just a syntactic sugar - under the hood it does the same as ES5 version

Comment: So just to clarify the website becomes faster rt ? To a small extent. Would you recommend this method or would u say that there rly is no diff

Comment: @Gokul Kurup, Albert Einstein would say - speed is relative :) But not only speed is important - app would use less resources, so server might cost less. Using advantages of prototype inheritance is definitely worth to take. And choosing between ES5 and ES6 versions, I dont know. ES6 is newer, so JS creators probably are smart people and knows how to do things better, so we should probably just follow them, however, new features are just syntactic sugar, so by learning only new features soon you might loose understanding how JS works under the hood. So I say - use ES6 only ifyou understand ES5

Comment: Ah I see. That makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I post this as a reference to others who have been faced with this dilemma.
First of all, ONe of the core issues for me was migrating from java, I seemed to be familiar territory but things work a bit different in js.I strongly recommend these links:

[Objects in Detail](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-objects-in-detail/)

[js Prototype](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-prototype-in-plain-detailed-language/)

So the key to why this method works is due to the

```
 window.friendlyapp =new friendlychat()
```

Now normally in most languages you have an object

```
obj() {
  attr : value
  method: function() {}
}
```

And then to use the method you do

```
var child = new obj();
child.method();
```

but in this method the var is made an instance of the window object and thats why none of the methods of the app need to be explicitly called.